# Twos complement on hex

Tags: hex, bitwise-operators, signed, twos-complement

Given:

```
int number = 0xFFFFFF87;
number = ~number + 1;
printf ("%x", number);
```

Why does 'number' become '79' instead of '87'? How can i make it '87' ?

Answer (score 1):

It is 0x79 because `~0xFFFFFF87 = 0x00000078` and when 1 is added you get `0x00000079`.

To get `0x87`, you should use:

```
int number = 0xFFFFFF87 & 0xFF;
```

which will select only the least significant byte and mask the other bytes with zero.

Answer (score 0):

`~` negates every bit, not only the ones with hex group of `0xF`.

To make it `0x87` just reverse the operation, i.e.:

```
int number = ~(0x87-1); // which is 0xFFFFFF79
```